# Mysql query with a Constraint, getting errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried converting a MSSQL query to MySQL, however, being inexperienced as I am, I am running into troubles here.

The query as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Appointments (
        `UniqueID` int AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
        `Type` int NULL ,
        `StartDate` Datetime NULL ,
        `EndDate` Datetime NULL ,
        `AllDay` Tinyint NULL ,
        `Subject` nvarchar (50) NULL ,
        `Location` nvarchar (50) NULL ,
        `Description` Longtext NULL ,
        `Status` int NULL ,
        `Label` int NULL ,
        `ResourceID` int NULL ,
        `ResourceIDs` Longtext NULL ,
        `ReminderInfo` Longtext NULL ,
        `RecurrenceInfo` Longtext NULL ,
        `CustomField1` Longtext NULL 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Appointments] PRIMARY KEY 
(
        `UniqueID` ASC
)
); TEXTIMAGE_ON `PRIMARY`

GO

CREATE TABLE Resources (
        `UniqueID` int AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
        `ResourceID` int NOT NULL ,
        `ResourceName` nvarchar (50) NULL ,
        `Color` int NULL ,
        `Image` Longblob NULL ,
        `CustomField1` Longtext NULL 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Resources] PRIMARY KEY 
(
        `UniqueID` ASC
)
); TEXTIMAGE_ON `PRIMARY`

GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT `dbo`.`Resources` ON
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] (`UniqueID`, `ResourceID`, `ResourceName`, `Color`, `Image`, `CustomField1`) SELECT (1, 1, N'Resource One', NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] (`UniqueID`, `ResourceID`, `ResourceName`, `Color`, `Image`, `CustomField1`) SELECT (2, 2, N'Resource Two', NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] (`UniqueID`, `ResourceID`, `ResourceName`, `Color`, `Image`, `CustomField1`) SELECT (3, 3, N'Resource Three', NULL, NULL, NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT `dbo`.`Resources` OFF

GO
```

And here is the result when I try to run this query.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT [PK_Appointments] PRIMARY KEY 
(
        `UniqueID` ASC
)
)' at line 20
```

Could anyone please help me fix this query?

Comment: Start by getting rid of all the square braces.

Comment: Remove the `CONSTRAINT` line entirely and just put `PRIMARY KEY` in your field definition,  after `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: The `CONSTRAINT constraint_name` is optional for the PRIMARY KEY constraint. (If it's included, it gets ignored.)  As Gordon said, eliminate the square brackets, by replacing them with backticks (or removing them if the identifiers don't need to be escaped.)  Also remove the `ASC` keyword, I don't believe MySQL supports that keyword in the key definition. And eliminate the lines that have `GO` on them. And also remove the `TEXTIMAGE_ON PRIMARY`. And remove the `dbo` qualifier on the insert statements. And replace `Nvarchar` with `varchar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   CREATE TABLE Appointments (
            `UniqueID` int AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
            `Type` int NULL ,
            `StartDate` Datetime NULL ,
            `EndDate` Datetime NULL ,
            `AllDay` Tinyint NULL ,
            `Subject` varchar (50) NULL ,
            `Location` varchar (50) NULL ,
            `Description` Longtext NULL ,
            `Status` int NULL ,
            `Label` int NULL ,
            `ResourceID` int NULL ,
            `ResourceIDs` Longtext NULL ,
            `ReminderInfo` Longtext NULL ,
            `RecurrenceInfo` Longtext NULL ,
            `CustomField1` Longtext NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (`UniqueID`)


    );

    CREATE TABLE Resources (
            `UniqueID` int AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
            `ResourceID` int NOT NULL ,
            `ResourceName` varchar (50) NULL ,
            `Color` int NULL ,
            `Image` Longblob NULL ,
            `CustomField1` Longtext NULL, 
             PRIMARY KEY(`UniqueID`) 
    );

    INSERT into Resources(`UniqueID`, `ResourceID`, `ResourceName`, `Color`, `Image`, `CustomField1`) values (1, 1, 'Resource One', NULL, NULL, NULL);
    INSERT into Resources(`UniqueID`, `ResourceID`, `ResourceName`, `Color`, `Image`, `CustomField1`) values (2, 2, 'Resource Two', NULL, NULL, NULL);
    INSERT into Resources(`UniqueID`, `ResourceID`, `ResourceName`, `Color`, `Image`, `CustomField1`) values (3, 3, 'Resource Three', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. TIL there's no need to use the CONSTRAINT word on Mysql.